# What is this monitor ? And where can i use it?

Tags: display, desktop-computer

I have this monitor and I don't have its port on my computer

the monitor:

[image]

Side view of the cable:

[image]

head view of the cable:

[image]

A port:
[image: A port]

Ports:
[image: Ports]

Comment: What would be more useful are pictures of any labels on the monitor ...

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other ports? It looks like Sony Vaio all in one - essential PC and display in one and the cable would be part of the PC, not a monitor. Please post a complete label and ports from the back on the device

Comment: OK I will post another question with all ports but there is only on cable coming out of this monitor and it have NO place in my computer

Comment: Instead of posting new questions, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1264956/edit) your question. // That being said, it’s most likely a proprietary connector, like a dock connector on notebooks.

Comment: Found it: It’s the monitor of a Sony VAIO LX computer. You can find an image [here](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/11/27/13751418/sony-design-history-products-tokyo-ginza-exhibit). It’s high-res and features both the display and the PC itself, with the proprietary port visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Google Image search for “sony vaio all in one” I was able to find an image of this machine, revealing its name: Sony VAIO LX. Available sometime around 2000, it featured a display with a “digitizer” for pen input. Apparently, it also had touch input, although unlike what we have today.

[The Verge has a gallery of ancient Sony products](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/11/27/13751418/sony-design-history-products-tokyo-ginza-exhibit) that also features this particular machine.

The connector is indeed proprietary, carrying at least USB, 2×PS/2 (Keyboard, Mouse) and the display signal itself.

I did, in fact, also find a supposed pinout on [this page](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/sony_vaio_pinout.shtml). Going by the pin names, it could potentially carry a single DVI link.

Comment: Thanks for this but can use it on a regular computer (versus)

Comment: Not without an adapter...